# How to fixed app name XCODE I can do this

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I can't fix app name, only for this project.

Searched google, tried all of them. It didn't get fixed.

```
Target > info > bundle name, bundle display name

supporing files> info.plist > bundle name > bumdle display name
```

product name fixed

other projects fixed very well, but this project I can't succeed.

this project I did rename the project's name.

so  I fixed targets> build settings > packaging > Info.plis File 
"[targets NAME]"/Info.plist

When I try itunes updating 
I can't see fixed appname  example fix "Rename"

but I confirm iPhone appname previous name ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> Make sure you are changing Product name of **Target** and not
>   **Projects**.

To rename app name go to Build Settings -> Product Name -> Change it to whatever you need.